# Wikipedia : Java library to remove wikipedia text markup removal

Tags: java, parsing, wiki, wikipedia

I downloaded wikipedia dump and now want to remove the wikipedia markup in the contents of each page. I tried writing regular expressions but they are too many to handle. I found a python library but I need a java library because, I want to integrate into my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Cloud you post a sample of a page showing the markups you want to remove?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

1. let some existing tool convert the MediaWiki mark-up into plain HTML;
2. convert the plain HTML into text.

The following demo:

```
import net.java.textilej.parser.MarkupParser;
import net.java.textilej.parser.builder.HtmlDocumentBuilder;
import net.java.textilej.parser.markup.mediawiki.MediaWikiDialect;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String markup = "This is ''italic'' and '''that''' is bold. \n"+
                "=Header 1=\n"+
                "a list: \n* item A \n* item B \n* item C";

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        HtmlDocumentBuilder builder = new HtmlDocumentBuilder(writer);
        builder.setEmitAsDocument(false);

        MarkupParser parser = new MarkupParser(new MediaWikiDialect());
        parser.setBuilder(builder);
        parser.parse(markup);

        final String html = writer.toString();
        final StringBuilder cleaned = new StringBuilder();

        HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback callback = new HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback() {
                public void handleText(char[] data, int pos) {
                    cleaned.append(new String(data)).append(' ');
                }
        };
        new ParserDelegator().parse(new StringReader(html), callback, false);

        System.out.println(markup);
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println(html);
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println(cleaned);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
This is ''italic'' and '''that''' is bold. 
=Header 1=
a list: 
* item A 
* item B 
* item C
---------------------------
<p>This is <i>italic</i> and <b>that</b> is bold. </p><h1 id="Header1">Header 1</h1><p>a list: </p><ul><li>item A </li><li>item B </li><li>item C</li></ul>
---------------------------
This is  italic  and  that  is bold. Header 1 a list: item A item B item C
```

> Where do you download the java packages you are importing?

Here: [Web Archive link of download.java.net/maven/2/net/java/textile-j/2.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20100228230847/http://download.java.net/maven/2/net/java/textile-j/2.2/)

Comment: Where do you download the java packages you are importing?

Comment: That worked great, thanks! It only missed a few other elements like {{...}} stuff.

Comment: Hi Bart, that download link is not working, is there any alternate source for download?

Comment: @kzs the link appears to be archived: I edited my answer to include this link and removed the dead link from the comments

Answer (score 3):

If you need plain text you should use WikiClean library https://github.com/lintool/wikiclean.

I had the same problem and it looks like this was the only efficient solution that worked for me in java.

There are two usecases:

1) When you have the text not in XML format then you should add xml tags needed to do this processing. Supposing you are processing XML file earlier, and now you have the content without XML structure, then you just add xmlStartTag and xmlEndTag as in the code bellow, and it processes it.

```
String xmlStartTag = "<text xml:space=\"preserve\">";
String xmlEndTag = "</text>";
String articleWithXml = xmlStartTag + article.getText() + xmlEndTag;
WikiClean cleaner = new WikiClean.Builder().build();
String plainWikiText = cleaner.clean(articleWithXml);
```

2) When you are reading the Wikipedia dump file directly (xml file), in that case you just pass it through the file and it goes through.

```
WikiClean cleaner = new WikiClean.Builder().build();
String plainWikiText = cleaner.clean(XMLFileContents);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18533404)

Comment: Thanks @Bhuwan. I updated my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Sh.Sina should I give the whole dump file as the input of clean() method? Isn't there any possibility that I get the cleaned text just for some page titles that I know? The library documentation is a bit misleadding. Where should I have the dump file as the input and where the page title?

Comment: @user1419243 Please refer to the case 1 mentioned in  my reponse. If you have the text, you just need to add the starting and ending xml tags and then it will be processed by the library. If you still have issues just paste your text and I will try to help :).

Comment: @Sh.Sina Thanks for your answer, but I still have the problem. My first question is where should I put the dump file. For example, I want to get the plain text of "Apache HTTP Server" page in Wikipedia. I have the dump file of wikipedia in "E:\\enwiki-20171103-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2". If I give the above text along with the mentioned tags, how does the library know that it should go through the dump file in E drive? I don't see anywhere in the code that load the dump file. And I don't want to crawl the whole dump file (right?). I don't need it. I have the pages that I need.

Comment: You can edit the dumpfile, it is a XML file. Remove all pages, leave only the pages that you want to be processed and viola :).

Answer (score 1):

[Mylyn WikiText](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Incubator/WikiText) can convert various Wiki syntaxes into HTML and other formats. It also supports MediaWiki syntax, which is what Wikipedia uses. Although Mylyn WikiText is primarily an Eclipse plugin, it is also [available as standalone library](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/).

Comment: I just need a function which can remove the wiki markup from the content. I am not sure how to use mylyn to remove the markup. Can you tell me how to do it.

Comment: @Algorist: Mylyn WikiText doesn't remove markup, it converts into other formats. I'm sorry, I have misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Mediawiki text to plain text](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/wiki/Mediawiki2PlainText) approach. You probably have to improve the PlainTextConverter class for your needs. 
Combined with the [example for converting Wikipedia texts to HTML](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/wiki/Mediawiki2HTML#Advanced_example_for_converting_Wikipedia_texts_to_HTML) you can transclude template contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jwiki](https://github.com/viralvaghela/Jwiki) to get Wikipedia data Example :

```
Jwiki jwiki = new Jwiki("elon musk");
System.out.println("Title :"+jwiki.getDisplayTitle()); //get title
System.out.println("Text : "+jwiki.getExtractText());  //get summary text
System.out.println("Image : "+jwiki.getImageURL());    //get image URL
```