# Converting Wikitext to plain text in Java

Tags: java, scripting, text, formatting

Any script available for converting Wikitext to Plain text? I prefer it implemented in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863272/wikipedia-java-library-to-remove-wikipedia-text-markup-removal).

Comment: Thanks. It'll just be copy & paste than. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there would have to be two steps involved:

1. First, convert the Wiki Text two
   HTML e.g. using [Textile](https://java.net/projects/textile-j)
2. Then, converting the HTML to plain
   text either via Regex (probably not
   a good idea) or a dedicated HTML
   parser like [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)