# java regex to clear mediawiki markup

Tags: java, regex, performance, mediawiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wikipedia : Java library to remove wikipedia text markup removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863272/wikipedia-java-library-to-remove-wikipedia-text-markup-removal)

I have to clean some content that comes from Confluence. That content is almost clean; however, there are some things like:

1. [link|]: A link without the url part
2. *[link|]*: A link (without the url part) in bold
3. *text*: Bolded text
4. _*text*_: italic bolded text

And so on.
I need to write a regex that clean all that, so, I did something like:

`String wikiCleanMarkupRegex = "\\\\[(.*?)[\\\\|.*?]?\\\\]|\\\\*(.*?)\\\\*|_(.*?)_";`

But that doesn't clean everything, I mean, if I give it the link in #2, I will get:

[link|]

Which is not what I want, I want to get "link"... so, I need to reparse the string again and again until no other match is found.

This is really slow because there are millions of records to clean, so, is there any way of doing a regex that does all at once?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, if I have something like \_\*\[link|\]\*\_: A link (without the url part) in bold and italic, I will need to parse it 3 times, one to remove the italic, other to remove the bold and the last one to remove the brackets... this is too slow for what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks that is basically three types of code formatting: *italic*, **bold**, and [LINK](http://pastebin.com/7WWwYMpy)

I'll do a 3-pass Regex replacer.

and the order of precedence according to the input you have given should be:

```
/**
 * FIRST REMOVE ITALICS, THEN BOLD, THEN URL
 */
public static String cleanWikiFormat(CharSequence sequence) {
    return Test.removeUrl(Test.removeBold(Test.removeItalic(sequence)));
}
```

Here's a sample code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Test {

    private static String removeItalic(CharSequence sequence) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("_\\*(.+?)\\*_");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(sequence);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(sequence.length());
        while (m.find()) {
            String text = m.group(1);
            // ... possibly process 'text' ...
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(text));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String removeBold(CharSequence sequence) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\*(.+?)\\*");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(sequence);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(sequence.length());
        while (m.find()) {
            String text = m.group(1);
            // ... possibly process 'text' ...
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(text));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }


    private static String removeUrl(CharSequence sequence) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[(.+?)\\|\\]");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(sequence);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(sequence.length());
        while (m.find()) {
            String text = m.group(1);
            // ... possibly process 'text' ...
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(text));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static String cleanWikiFormat(CharSequence sequence) {
        return Test.removeUrl(Test.removeBold(Test.removeItalic(sequence)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "[hello|] this is just a *[test|]* to clean wiki *type* and _*formatting*_";
        System.out.println("Original");
        System.out.println(text);
        text = Test.cleanWikiFormat(text);
        System.out.println("CHANGED");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

The following will give:

```
Original
[hello|] this is just a *[test|]* to clean wiki *type* and _*formatting*_
CHANGED
hello this is just a test to clean wiki type and formatting
```